# Google maps crashes in ios7. How can I solve this issue?

Tags: google-maps, safari, ios7

I have an application with google maps and I'm using a lot of markers in the map. The app crashes in iOS7 after displaying a memory warning. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: showing lesser markers is an option?

Comment: unfortunately that is not an option

Answer (score 1):

Implement a marker cluster:

Like this one: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers